# Converting .htaccess (PHP) line to web.config line (IIS)

Tags: .htaccess, web-config, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have these lines in my .htaccess file and have moved my site to an IIS environment.  I'm pretty sure it needs to go into a web.config file in the root but I'm totally lost and tried everything with no luck.  What this does is directs anything with .php, .htm, or .html to the index.php page in the root so I can control what is displayed and make things modular.  It will tack on the filename in the query string so I can direct the content from there.  Anyways heres what I have for .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (\.php|.htm|.html)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import and convert `mod_rewrite rules` to `IIS URL rewrite rules` using this Microsoft supported [URL Rewrite IIS Manager module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

**`web.config`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.(php|htm|html)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I GREATLY appreciate you pointing me back in the direction of the url rewrite module.  I had already tried to use that but didnt know it had the import feature!!  After I imported the .htaccess lines it still wasnt working (as is expected with an import lol), but after I adjusted the reqex slightly all is working!!!  Thank you again for helping me out.  For anyone thats wants the correct web.config setup for this here it is :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="(.*php|.*htm|.*html)$" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```